# Alfresco share customization in out of the box modules

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am new to alfresco (community) and I want to make some basic customization in alfresco's out of the box modules,Discussion module,specifically I want to add some new fields in it and that should be reflect in database of alfresco.
As first step I configured alfresco maven SDK?
And is it possible with Maven SDK or I have to go for any other programming model.[image: Same for discussion]

I want a new field in this form..

Answer (score 1):

I think that you don't need SDK, try to use Alfresco Model Manager:

- [Content modeling with Model Manager - intro](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/admintools-cmm-intro.html)
- [This video shows you how to create models in Alfresco](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t21IU6U1HRI)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and let me check link provided by you.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to make discussion categorized. for eg when some user create a new post he/she may prompt to select category from the given list(Dropdown).

Comment: so, post is a new type containing "category" property (list of values)... you can do this with model manager

Comment: so you're telling that it can be done through UI only right?

Comment: yes, 1. new model "discussion", 2. new type "post", 3. new property "category"... and site + rule that specialize type of all content to "post"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128061/discussion-between-imagine-and-bhaumik-thakkar).

Comment: and yes i am using community version! sorry i forgot to remind you.

Comment: Have you made any progress?

Comment: nope i tried a lot as you told no solution..
the solution you provide that will work when someone will add content(doc.) in discussion folder(repo -> site -> discussion) folder.

Comment: when i post any dis. topic it will posted directly and as you told that it'll add a new controller in create topic form that also didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128270/discussion-between-imagine-and-bhaumik-thakkar).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a rule that would add the classifiable aspect to topics when they are created? That would be the most straightforward way to go.

If that doesn't work you can always just create your own aspect with a custom property. The property can be defined in the content model to have a constraint if your list of categories is hard-coded.

Once you've defined your property in the content model, you'll need to add the aspect to topics. You can do that with a rule, or you can write a Java-based behavior to add it.

With that in place you should be able to edit your Share form configuration to expose the new property as a dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but actually I don't want to add a new field in property, I want to create a new field in create new discussion form.And I also tried by creating a new rule. it didn't works.

Comment: And when I create any simple discussion with just some text content than it will not create a file in that Discussion folder.

Comment: I've read your revised post and looked at your screenshot. What I am proposing is how you would implement that.

Comment: I do not have idea about it! and i tried as you suggested me to do..but that didn't worked.